# Android: Hide my reminder notification when it has been clicked

Tags: android, notifications

I have a notification system in my android app, when the notification time has arrived my notification shown in the notification bar and when user clicked on it, my app opens, but still the notification shown in notification bar. How can hide notification from notification bar when user clicked on it?

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Calendar now = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();      
    Bundle bund = intent.getExtras();
    String text = bund.getString("name", "");
        Notification.Builder mBuilder = 
                new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setSound(android.provider.Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle( text)
                .setContentText("text");
        Toast.makeText(context,"ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(Main.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
   // }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you try?

```
mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
```